# My simple REST call to openweathermap not working - Error: No JSON object could be decoded

Tags: python, json, rest, urllib2, openweathermap

My code is very simple. When I run the code below, I should be getting a JSON back as I can see when I paste the `url` directly in the browser but when I try using Python, I get the error

> ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded

```
import urllib2
import json

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0'

json_obj = urllib2.urlopen(url)
data = json.load(json_obj) #THIS IS LINE 7, i.e. where the error occurs
```

Here is the full error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 291, in load
  **kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of urllib.

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import requests

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0'

r = requests.get(url)
print r.status_code
print r.json()
>>> {u'clouds': {u'all': 0}, u'name': u'London', u'coord': {u'lat': 51.51, u'lon': -0.13}, u'sys': {u'country': u'GB', u'sunset': 1453393861, u'message': 0.0089, u'type': 1, u'id': 509
1, u'sunrise': 1453362798}, u'weather': [{u'main': u'Clear', u'id': 800, u'icon': u'01n', u'description': u'Sky is Clear'}], u'cod': 200, u'base': u'cmc stations', u'dt': 145340535
4, u'main': {u'pressure': 1022, u'temp_min': 276.85, u'temp_max': 279.15, u'temp': 277.76, u'humidity': 70}, u'id': 2643743, u'wind': {u'speed': 3.6, u'deg': 150}}
```

From requests [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content):

> In case the JSON decoding fails, r.json raises an exception. For
>   example, if the response gets a 204 (No Content), or if the response
>   contains invalid JSON, attempting `r.json` raises `ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded`.

So check what kind of status code you get back `r.status_code` and based on your second comment there is an `UTF` problem.

Comment: I tried EXACTLY what you pasted, still getting `JSONDecodeError`. Could this be because I am on Windows? http://imgur.com/a04Uv6W

Comment: @user1406716 hm, maybe (not sure about this), I am on Linux

Comment: @user1406716 what `r.text` returns?

Comment: @user1406716 add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` as the very first line of your script